# How do I tag correctly when posting a new question

Tags: support, faq, tagging

When posting a question, or when updating tags, the FAQ suggests I

1. Check the list of existing tags
2. Read the tag wiki to understand what each means

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see the list of tags, click on the [tags](https://security.stackexchange.com/tags) button at the top of the page.

To see the tag wiki, click on any tag - either on the tag list, or on a post, and the relevant wiki page for that tag will come up.

Comment: Also you can hover your mouse over the tag (in most places) and a popup with the tag wiki summary will display.

Comment: On that note - we need to populate the twikis!

Comment: @avid I've been wanting to do that for a while.  But only 6 people can do so now....  See my meta question just now on reducing the limits.  http://meta.security.stackexchange.com/questions/149/can-we-reduce-the-limits-for-editing-the-tag-wiki